# Java OCR Help Needed

Tags: java, ocr

How do I detect all the characters in an image? The image is in png and the font is constant. For simplicity, lets assume that the image has only numeric digits and there are only 4 digits on an image. I need to read all of them and output the text.

Can you help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried http://neuroph.sourceforge.net? 
It has all the stuff you will need in order to achieve this.

An in case you have also the flexibility to use .NET-framework, then check for AForge Framework from Andrew Kirillov.